# can't Access Payment methods (under Sales ) in magento Admin Panel after server migration

Tags: admin-panel

I can't Access system -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment methods after server migration. its shows server error 500

**log details:**

```
2016-02-01T10:38:27+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96

2016-02-01T10:38:27+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98

2016-02-01T10:38:27+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100

2016-02-01T10:38:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 90: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

2016-02-01T10:38:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 56

2016-02-01T10:38:33+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_ECB - assumed 'MCRYPT_MODE_ECB'  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 60
```

link : index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/

[image]

Comment: Enable logging and check your log files. Post their content as an edit to the question. Only then, it will be possible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Prateek i updated the log details. am using Centos6

Comment: Looks like `mcrypt` is not installed in your new server. Check with the your hosting and get it installed. This link might help further : http://www.magestore.com/magento-installation/test-server-for-compatibility-with-magento

Comment: @Prateek i understood my problem clearly. thx u for ur support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `mcrypt` is not installed in your new server. Check with the your hosting and get it installed. This link might help further : http://www.magestore.com/magento-installation/test-server-for-compatibility-with-magento

Answer (score 1):

Please install mcrypt.
You can do the following steps.

Sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

And then restart your apache sever.

Sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

i follow the following steps to install mcrypt.

```
# yum install epel-release
```

Then, i installed the php-mcrypt module:

```
# yum install php-mcrypt
```

finally i restarted my server. now its working fine